# Webservice call from .net class called from VB6

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, vb6, endpoint

Im using VB6 in a project and I've some .Net dlls to handle document transfers.
In one of these dlls im calling a webservice to retrieve my documents. This code works if only run as .net project, however running from vb6 it gives me the following error:

"Could not find endpoint element with name "DocServiceSoap' and contract 'documentWebService.DocServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element"

I've googled around and tried everything, e.g. copying  from app.config to web.config, specifying endpoint name when calling for service, still no luck :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your app.config is called `myDotNetDll.dll.config`? That's wrong. The config file always need to be attached to the executable file.

So, to solve your issue, you need to copy it to your VB6 application, i.e., it should be called `myVb6Application.exe.config` and located in the same directory as your `myVb6Application.exe`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, however I need to compile an .exe to make this work (does not work in debug mode) any workarounds?

Comment: If you want it to work inside the VB6 development environment, you need to copy the configuration file to vb6.exe.config (in the directory of your vb6.exe, then restart VB6).